# Where can I download the old Xamarin Studios with Android package?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I just found a Xamarin Studio without Android package and Visual Studio is no option because it takes loads of disk space and is unnecessarily bloated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just have version 6.1.2(build 44) of Xamarin studio like the following screenshot, if you need it, you can download it with [this link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiMMFvbE9tNIj1VLBWkYMO16CAPt)

[image]